# finality of block number returned by `getBlockNumber()` in ethersjs

Tags: ethers.js, the-merge

In the latest version of ethersjs `5.7.0` , does `getBlockNumber()` method return the height of the latest finalized block or the safe block?

context: https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/issues/3091

Answer (score 2):

`getBlockNumber` uses *latest* (neither *safe* nor *finalized*).

You can use `getBlock` instead of `getBlockNumber`. Use `getBlock('finalized').number` and you get the latest finalized block number.

But it seems that they plan to support tags for `getBlockNumber` at some point.

**Reference**:

- See this post: https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/discussions/3068
- And especially this reply: https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/discussions/3068#discussioncomment-4043453

Comment: Welcome back! Nice